# If $\mathrm{d}(\mathcal{A})=1$ and $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis, does $\mathcal{A}+\mathcal{B}\sim \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, additive-combinatorics

> If $\mathcal{A}\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ is a set with asymptotic density $\mathrm{d}(\mathcal{A}):= \lim_{n\to\infty} |\mathcal{A}\cap[1,n]|/n = 1$, does $\mathcal{A}+\mathcal{B}$ always contains all but finitely many natural numbers, for every asymptotic bases $\mathcal{B}$?

I came up with this question by reading [this survey](https://www.math.cmu.edu/~af1p/Teaching/AdditiveCombinatorics/Additive-Combinatorics.pdf) on sumsets by I. Ruzsa. On Sections 4.6  and 4.7 (pp 77-81) he describes two theorems on how the (Schnirelmann's) density of an addition of a basis $\mathcal{B}$ to a set with positive lower asymp. density $\mathcal{A}$ can be bounded below in terms of the order of $\mathcal{B}$ and $\underline{\mathrm{d}}(\mathcal{A})$. Nonetheless, having $\mathrm{d}(\mathcal{A}+\mathcal{B})=1$ does not say anything about having all large integers or not!

I was able to prove it true when $\underline{\mathrm{d}}(\mathcal{B})>0$, and it goes by considering $n_0\in\mathbb{N}:\forall n\geqslant n_0$ holds
$$|\mathcal{A}\cap[1,n]|>(1-\underline{\mathrm{d}}(\mathcal{B}))n,$$

thus, for every large $n$, there must be some $b\in\mathcal{B}: n-b\in\mathcal{A}$.

The case $\underline{\mathrm{d}}(\mathcal{B})=0$ seem a bit more elusive, though.

Comment: Does $B$ being an asymptotic basis mean that there exist $k_1$ and $k_2$  such that for all $n \gt k_1,$ $n$ can written as the sum of exactly $k_2$ members of $B?$

Comment: @MitchellSpector Exactly! I am not sure if this is a necessary condition for $A+B$ to have all suff. large integers, but I think it must be sufficient.